# IndexOutOfBoundsException when writing dataframe into CSV

Tags: scala, apache-spark, arraylist, apache-spark-sql

So, I'm trying to read an existing file, save that into a DataFrame, once that's done I make a "union" between that existing DataFrame and a new one I have already created, both have the same columns and share the same schema.

*ALSO I CANNOT GIVE SIGNIFICANT NAME TO VARS NOR GIVE ANYMORE DATA BECAUSE OF RESTRICTIONS*

```
val dfExist = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").schema(schema).load(filePathAggregated3) 
val df5 = df4.union(dfExist)
```

Once that's done I get the "start_ts" (a timestamp on Epoch format) that's duplicate in the union between the above dataframes (df4 and dfExist) and also I get rid of some characters I don't want

```
val df6 = df5.select($"start_ts").collect()
val df7 = df6.diff(df6.distinct).distinct.mkString.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
```

Now I use this "start_ts" duplicate to filter the DataFrame and create 2 new DataFrames selecting the items of this duplicate timestamp, and the items that are not like this duplicate timestamp

```
val itemsNotDup = df5.filter(!$"start_ts".like(df7)).select($"start_ts",$"avg_value",$"Number_of_val")
val items = df5.filter($"start_ts".like(df7)).select($"start_ts",$"avg_value",$"Number_of_val")
```

And then I save in 2 different lists the avg_value and the Number_of_values

```
items.map(t => t.getAs[Double]("avg_value")).collect().foreach(saveList => listDataDF += saveList.toString)
items.map(t => t.getAs[Long]("Number_of_val")).collect().foreach(saveList => listDataDF2 += saveList.toString)
```

Now I make some maths with the values on the lists (THIS IS WHERE I'M GETTING ISSUES)

```
val newAvg = ((listDataDF(0).toDouble*listDataDF2(0).toDouble) - (listDataDF(1).toDouble*listDataDF2(1).toDouble)) / (listDataDF2(0) + listDataDF2(1)).toInt
val newNumberOfValues = listDataDF2(0).toDouble + listDataDF2(1).toDouble
```

Then save the duplicate timestamp (df7), the avg and the number of values into a list as a single item, this list transforms into a DataFrame and then I transform I get a new DataFrame with the columns how are supposed to be.

```
listDataDF3 += df7 + ',' + newAvg.toString + ',' + newNumberOfValues.toString + ','
val listDF = listDataDF3.toDF("value")
val listDF2 = listDF.withColumn("_tmp", split($"value", "\\,")).select(
            $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("start_ts"),
            $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("avg_value"),
            $"_tmp".getItem(2).as("Number_of_val")
          ).drop("_tmp")
```

Finally I join the DataFrame without duplicates with the new DataFrame which have the duplicate timestamp and the avg of the duplicate avg values and the sum of number of values.

```
val finalDF = itemsNotDup.union(listDF2)
finalDF.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("csv").option("header","true").save(filePathAggregated3)
```

When I run this code in SPARK it gives me the error, I supposed it was related to empty lists (since it's giving me the error when making some maths with the values of the lists) but If I delete the line where I write to CSV, the code runs perfectly, also I saved the lists and values of the math calcs into files and they are not empty.

My supposition, is that, is deleting the file before reading it (because of how spark distribute tasks between workers) and that's why the list is empty therefore I'm getting this error when trying to make maths with those values.

I'm trying to be as clear as possible but I cannot give much more details, nor show any of the output.

So, how can I avoid this error? also I've been only 1 month with scala/spark so any code recommendation will be nice as well.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem related to reading files, I made a check (df.rdd.isEmpty) and wether the DF was empty I was getting this error. Made this as an if/else statement to check if the DF is empty, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because of the Data. Any of your list does not contains columns as expected. When you refer to that index, the List gives this error to you

Comment: I checked the list, saved it into a file, it haves the number of items expected, also as I mention I only get this error when I try to save the dataframe, otherwise it works correctly.

Comment: You are running a show command which samples  the data an shows it to you. It is not an action. I would suggest run a df.count on your final data. you will get the error too. Try to perform an action on each step to debug the data discrepancies

Comment: Im not running a show command, because I dont have a screen I'm literally iterating on the list and saving it into a txt, it shows the values.

Comment: Can you please check df7  has any values or not

Comment: Yep, I did, 1 value which is the duplicate timestamp.